# Bundle install mess

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, installation, bundler

I have using RVM on a mac for a rails 3 development.

I wanted to run `bundle update newrelic_rpm` to upgrade to the new version of the gem.

This was a bad idea: it creates a new folder call newrelic_rpm at the root of my app, and bundle (v 1.0.10) displays proudly

`Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./newrelic_rpm`

And now i'm stuck, i cannot update my bundle and it keeps putting all my gems in the newly created folder.

can anyone please help me revert to the initial setup (and get rid of this ./newrelic_rpm folder)?

thanks!
p.

Comment: Which version of bundler are you using? (`bundle --version`)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm assuming that you first tried something like `bundle install newrelic_rpm`, which created the `newrelic_rpm` folder and told Bundler to start using that folder as the default.

Your `.bundle/config` file likely contains something like this:

```
---
BUNDLE_PATH: newreli_rpm
BUNDLE_DISABLE_SHARED_GEMS: "1"
```

The easiest way to fix this (assuming your Bundler is up to date), is to run this command to install everything back in the main shared system paths:

```
bundle install --system
```

Then, `bundle update newrelic_rpm` should do what you intended (updating the `newrelic_rpm` gem, rather than updating everything and putting it in `newrelic_rpm`).

Answer (score 1):

First: make backup. Then try removing '.bundle' directory.
Or just see the '.bundle/config' file - I guess there will be something interesting.

Comment: as anticipated by dmarkow, there was indeed something interesting :)